# Run eloquent package in foxy fitzroy?

Tags: ros, ros2, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i developed a package in ROS2 Eloquent and i want to know if i could run this exact package in foxy fitzroy
or do i have to expect that errors will occur?
I don't know the difference between Eloquent and Foxy and how the packages will run. and what to expect.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373928/run-eloquent-package-in-foxy-fitzroy-?/) by [anonymous71685](https://answers.ros.org/users/71685/anonymous71685/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2021-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without additional information, it is hard to tell you if you could run packages across distributions. You need to look at the dependencies and establish if they can operate across distributions. Why don't you try to build the package from source and see what happens?

---

Originally posted by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) with karma: 459 on 2021-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0